# Vim not indenting javascript block comments properly

Tags: javascript, vim

If I run vim's auto indent over this block of code:

```
/**
 * Some description here
 *
 * @return {?string}
 */
```

I get

```
/**
* Some description here
*
* @return {?string}
*/
```

Instead of what it was originally (desired behavior)
This is some new behavior, as previous this was being done correctly.

I'm using vim-javascript plugin, and my vimrc has

```
sytanx on
set autoindent
set smartindent
```

Comment: Did you try indenting using `gg=G` ?

Comment: @bk2dcradle Yes, same issue.

Comment: Witch js syntax plugin are you using ? You can try this one: https://github.com/utix/vim-javascript

Comment: @Ôrel The most popular one: pangloss/vim-javascript

Comment: You should othet conf breaking the indent. What is your cinoptions ? Have you try with an empty vimrc ?